# python output unexpected behaviour

Tags: python

Following program is used to sort a list

```
    for i in range(len(q)):
        for j in range(len(q)):
            if not (q[i] < q[j]):
                t = q[i]
                q[i] = q[j]
                q[j] = t
```

contents of q are : {-1 2 4}

The output I get has one empty number like:

4

-1
2

i.e. extra number (empty) between 4 and -1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you're doing wrong is not showing us the code that does the output.

Comment: It works for me - I end up with [4, 2, -1].   BTW the pythonic way to swap two values is `q[i], q[j] = q[j], q[i]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to sort a list?

```
your_list.sort()
```